# Difference between spüren and fühlen

Tags: word-choice, difference, meaning

As far as I know, *spüren* and *fühlen* both can be translated to *to feel.* Are there situations where one is more right than the other? I have a feeling that *spüren* is used more with external stimuli and *fühlen* with internal feelings and emotions, is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.

*Fühlen* is less reflected, it refers to feeling your own emotions and things directly touching your skin.

*Spüren* is less direct. It can also refer to things touching your skin (though not to emotions), but is more often used in a more indirect, metaphorical sense – you "spürst" the tension in a room, you do not "fühlen" it.

The difference is fluid, however, and not clear-cut (and perhaps even dependent on dialect). Referring to your own emotions, however, you never say *spüren*.

If this answer is confusing, I think it's because language is messy.

Answer (score 2):

I personally feel that *spüren* is a little more narrow in the sense that there are fewer situations in which *spüren* is most appropriate than there are for *fühlen*. *Fühlen* can be employed more universally as it can describe **both a sentiment and a sensory experience**, whereas *spüren* tends to be **limited to describing sensory experience**.

Also, *fühlen* can be reflexive *(sich gut/schlecht/einsam fühlen)* describing a sentiment, whereas a reflexive use of *spüren (sich spüren)* sounds highly peculiar and would perhaps describe a sensory experience of experiencing ones own being.

Of course this distinction is not absolutely clear, but perhaps it can give you a *Gefühl*.

Comment: I wouldn't agree that "spüren" is limited to describing sensory experience. I can very well imagine "spüren"ing an atmosphere, tension, etc. (as mentioned in adhominem's answer). A reflexive "spüren" in the sense of "sich fühlen" is truly impossible, but in all other cases I can think of, it doesn't sound awkward to replace "fühlen" by "spüren". In my view, "spüren" is a more subtle and precise way of "fühlen" (it also sounds a little more poetic and less everyday-language to my ears).

Comment: To complete my comment above, I can even "spüren" fear or wrath, when they develop inside me. "Da spürte ich, wie sich die Angst in mir breit machte", for example. Again, I think I could detect that "Angst" via "spüren" earlier than via "fühlen", because "spüren" has a lower detection threshold, so to speak.